# Is it adivsable to use DOMDocument on Wordpress content?

Tags: wordpress, domdocument

I'd like to tinker with the content Worpress generates before it gets displayed.

A lot of examples I saw so far use regex to change the content even though it is bad practise and not advisable to parse html with regex.

My idea now is to use DOMDocument to parse and change the HTML. Is that a good idea or can this break the integrity of the content in any way?

Here is some example Wordpress content filter I created (it scales the images down half the size for retina displays):

```
function fancyContentParser( $content ) {

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($content);

    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($images as $image) {

        $width = $image->getAttribute('width')/2;
        $height = $image->getAttribute('height')/2;
        $style = 'width: '.$width.'px; height: '.$height.'px';

        $image->setAttribute('style', $style); 

    }

    return $dom->saveHTML();

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'fancyContentParser' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers to this question are probably going to be primarily opinion-based...but I don't see anything wrong with it. However, why wouldn't you  just change the width and height attributes, rather than overriding them with `style`?

```
foreach ($images as $image) {

    $image->setAttribute( 'width', $image->getAttribute('width')/2 );
    $image->setAttribute( 'height', $image->getAttribute('width')/2 );

}
```

Additionally, you can likely accomplish this without DOMDocument...and just use CSS (which is what you're proposing in your question by using a `style` attribute anyways). You can use the `transform` property:

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
            transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Comment: Exactly .. answer to this question is probably going to be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: sure, i can adjust the width/height attributes rather than style but that is not my issue. transfrom is crap btw as it leaves white space around the transformed image the size of the original image. 

i also don't think my question leads to optinion-based answers. e.g. i just found out that DOMDocument has trouble with utf-8 characters so that is a pitfall right there and this is the kind of hint i am looking for.